# Automating ConcurrencyMode set to Fix in EDMX

Tags: entity-framework-4, concurrency, edmx

Majority of our tables in our models has a field called "intConcurrencyID" that we intended to use for concurrency checking. I believe the only way to enable this field for concurrency checking in a Database First environment is to set the Concurrency Mode to Fixed.

However, if we have huge numbers of tables per EDMX, we will have a hard time manually configuring each type per entity not to mention the possibility of some entities to be overlooked.

Do you have any ideas on how I can automate this process? It seems that T4 Template is not the way to go since the Concurrency Mode is in the CSDL not in the Code Behind..

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the edmx file before and after changing a property's concurrency mode and came up with a solution as a console app which parses the edmx file starting with the storage model for 'timestamp' columns and modifies the conceptual model by following the mappings.  This is a fairly robust solution, but it has some caveats.

I'm using MSSQL 2008, for which the timestamp/rowversion is the defacto concurrency type.  In my models I only use this type as a concurrency token.  If you use it in other places, but have a consistent name used for all concurrency tokens instead, I've included code for this scenario that can be uncommented.  If you simply use a different concurrency type and that type is unique to concurrency columns, you can change the type from 'timestamp' in this line of code:

```
           IEnumerable<XElement> storageEntities =
            from el in ssdl.Descendants(XName.Get("EntityType",ssdlNS))
            where (from prop in el.Elements(XName.Get("Property",ssdlNS)) where prop.Attribute("Type").Value == "timestamp" select prop).Count()>0
            select el;
```

If your concurrency pattern is more complicated, this code won't suffice.

That being said, I whipped this up in about an hour and ran it and it worked great for me on a model with nearly 200 entities, saving me a lot of annoyance going through the sluggish edmx designer, so I'm sure others will benefit.  This is a console application so you can put this in the prebuild step of your model project to integrate it into your build process.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConfigureConcurrency
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string edmxPath = args[0]; //or replace with a fixed path

            if (edmxPath == null || edmxPath.Length == 0)
                return;

            string edmxNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx";
            string ssdlNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl";
            string csdlNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm";
            string mapNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs";

            XElement root = XElement.Load(edmxPath);
            //Storage Model
            XElement ssdl = root.Descendants(XName.Get("StorageModels", edmxNS)).FirstOrDefault();
            //Conceptual
            XElement csdl = root.Descendants(XName.Get("ConceptualModels", edmxNS)).FirstOrDefault();
            //Mapping
            XElement map = root.Descendants(XName.Get("Mappings", edmxNS)).FirstOrDefault();

            /*
             Use this code instead of the line below it, if the type of your concurrency columns is used on other non-concurrency columns
             and you use the same name for every concurrency column             

            string ConcurrencyColumnName = "RowVersion";
            IEnumerable<XElement> storageEntities =
                from el in ssdl.Descendants(XName.Get("EntityType", ssdlNS))
                where (from prop in el.Elements(XName.Get("Property", ssdlNS)) where prop.Attribute("Name").Value == ConcurrencyColumnName select prop).Count() > 0
                select el;
            */

            IEnumerable<XElement> storageEntities =
                from el in ssdl.Descendants(XName.Get("EntityType",ssdlNS))
                where (from prop in el.Elements(XName.Get("Property",ssdlNS)) where prop.Attribute("Type").Value == "timestamp" select prop).Count()>0
                select el;

            //for each timestamp column, find the mapping then find the conceptual model property and establish the concurrency mode
            foreach(XElement storageEntity in storageEntities) 
            {
                //Get the mapping
                XElement mapping = (from el in map.Descendants(XName.Get("EntityTypeMapping",mapNS)) where el.Element(XName.Get("MappingFragment",mapNS)).Attribute("StoreEntitySet").Value == storageEntity.Attribute("Name").Value select el).FirstOrDefault();

                if (mapping != null)
                {
                    //Get the column mapping
                    XElement column = (from el in storageEntity.Descendants(XName.Get("Property",ssdlNS)) where el.Attribute("Type").Value == "timestamp" select el).FirstOrDefault();
                    string columnName = column.Attribute("Name").Value;
                    XElement columnMapping = (from el in mapping.Descendants(XName.Get("ScalarProperty",mapNS)) where el.Attribute("ColumnName").Value == columnName select el).FirstOrDefault();
                    string propertyName = columnMapping.Attribute("Name").Value;

                    //Get the conceptual schema namespace and type name
                    string[] split = mapping.Attribute("TypeName").Value.Split('.');

                    string ns="", typeName =split[split.Length-1];

                    for (int i = 0; i < split.Length-1; i++)
                    {
                        if (i>0)
                            ns+=".";

                        ns += split[i];
                    }

                    //Find the entry in the conceptual model
                    XElement schema = (from el in csdl.Elements(XName.Get("Schema",csdlNS)) where el.Attribute("Namespace").Value == ns select el).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (schema != null)
                    {
                        //Find the entity type
                        XElement entity = (from el in schema.Descendants(XName.Get("EntityType",csdlNS)) where el.Attribute("Name").Value == typeName select el).FirstOrDefault();

                        //Find the property
                        XElement concurrencyProperty = (from el in entity.Elements(XName.Get("Property",csdlNS)) where el.Attribute("Name").Value == propertyName select el).FirstOrDefault();

                        //Set concurrency mode to fixed
                        concurrencyProperty.SetAttributeValue("ConcurrencyMode", "Fixed");
                    }
                }
            }

            //Save the modifications
            root.Save(edmxPath);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved my similar problem with the above console app. 
But if you are running a later version of Entity Framework, be sure to update references to schemas. I am using EF 5 and for me I used the following lines:

```
string edmxNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx";
string ssdlNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl";
string csdlNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm";
string mapNS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs";
```