# synchronization between 2 applications pooling a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework-6

I have 2 instances of a VB.NET application each running on their own dedicated servers. The said application runs a While true loop with a 5s sleep on IDLE (IDLE is when the Table doesn't have any ProcessQuery to be treated). On each iteration, the application questions a table in the SQL Database to know if there is anything it could process.

The problem is that i sometimes encounter the problem where both of the instances are "taking" the same ProcessQuery.

I'm using EntityFramework6. I have looked into EntityState but i don't think it does exactly what i'm trying to accomplish.

I was wondering what would be my solution to have perfect parallel instances. It's not impossible at some point i have 12 instances running on 12 machines.

Thanks!

```
 Dim conn As New Info_IndusEntities()
    Dim DemandeWilma As WilmaDemandes =  conn.WilmaDemandes.Where(Function(x) x.Site = 'LONDON' AndAlso x.Statut = 'toProcess').OrderBy(Function(x) x.RequestDate).FirstOrDefault

            If Not IsNothing(DemandeWilma) Then
                DemandeWilma.Statut = Statuts.EnTraitement.ToString
                DemandeWilma.ServerName = Environment.MachineName
                DemandeWilma.ProcessDate = DateTime.Now
                conn.SaveChanges()
                Return DemandeWilma
            end if
```

---

**UPDATE (21/06/19)**

I found [an article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/handle-concurrency-in-entity-framework.aspx) that I find interesting.

I started by adding a column to my Table :
[image]

**UPDATED (21/06/19)**

I then refreshed my model and changed the *Concurrency Check* property of RowVersion column in my ORM :

[image]

When I tested the update, here's the log of EF6 :

> UPDATE [dbo].[WilmaDemandes] SET [Statut] = @0, [ServerName] = @1,
>   [DateDebut] = @2 WHERE (([ID] = @3) AND ([RowVersion] = @4)) SELECT
>   [RowVersion] FROM [dbo].[WilmaDemandes] WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID]
>   = @3
>
> -- @0: 'EnTraitement' (Type = String, Size = 20)
>
> -- @1: 'TRB5995' (Type = String, Size = 20)
>
> -- @2: '2019-06-25 7:31:01 AM' (Type = DateTime2)
>
> -- @3: '124373' (Type = Int32)
>
> -- @4: 'System.Byte[]' (Type = Binary, Size = 8)
>
> -- Executing at 2019-06-25 7:31:24 AM -04:00
>
> -- Completed in 95 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Closed connection at 2019-06-25 7:31:24 AM -04:00
>
> Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' in
>   EntityFramework.dll

**UPDATED (25/06/19)**

The problems, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384242/entity-framework-db-first-timestamp-column-not-working), starts when you are using DB-First instead of Code-First. Your property will get **overwritten silently** as soon as you update the model. Some people back then coded a console app workaround that they run on pre-build. I'm not sure i'm quite ready to take this solution as final solution.

[Interesting tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/concurrency) on how to test optimistic concurrency and ways to resolve such an exception.

Comment: I think [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-2017) might be what you are looking for

Comment: If your applications are essentially processing a queue of work items, consider using Service Broker, which was designed for this. A single conversation/message queue can have multiple readers, with each message going to only one reader. There is a bit of a learning curve/retooling involved, though. Sticking to tables, you can use serializable transactions to "mark" rows as reserved, or use `sp_getapplock` to lock without using rows. (I don't recommend the latter, because it's easy to accidentally orphan locks if you're not careful with your transactions.)

Comment: @GuidoG Your solution implies that I would have 12 databases of I wanna run 12 instances of my application. I don't think it's a viable solution as the maintenance of these instances would become a nightmare.

Comment: You wrote you can have up to 12 databases running, not 12 instances of your application. Replication is just one possible way to do it, since we dont know all details (and you did not share them here) only you can know if its a way that is doable for you or not. Anyway, for replication to work, no application needs to run

Comment: @GuidoG I've updated the original post. Thanks for info

Comment: Not relevant, but `If DemandeWilma IsNot Nothing` is more readable

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an "owner" column to your queue table
2. Your application updates one record (TOP 1) and sets the owner value to their identifier (WHERE Owner IS NULL)
3. Now your application goes back and reads their owned rows and processes them

It's a simple pattern and it works great. If any processes happen to take ownership 'simultaneously', only one will actually get the reservation.

I'm not very good at LINQ so here's a brute force method, multiline for clarity:

```
// First try reserving a row
conn.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
  "WITH UpdateTop1 AS 
   (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM WilmaDemandes
    WHERE Owner IS NULL 
    AND Site = 'LONDON'
    ORDER BY RequestDate) 

    UPDATE UpdateTop1 SET Owner='ThisApplication'"
);

// See if we got one 
Dim DemandeWilma As WilmaDemandes =  
conn.WilmaDemandes.
Where(x => x.Owner=='ThisApplication').FirstOrDefault

// If we got a row, process it. Otherwise Idle and repeat
```

There's also no reason that you must reserve one row. You could reserve all the free rows and work your way through them. Meanwhile other processes will pick up any subsequently arriving rows

Personally I would refactor your status column and make it NULL for new records ready to be processed, otherwise it's the worker ID that has reserved it.

It also helps to add things like timestamp columns to record when the row was reserved etc.

Comment: I've edited the original Post. I added a code sample showing what the application does to get the first ProcessQuery to be treated. I feel like i'm missing something when i comed to EF6. My first idea was to add a where clause to the update query but i'm not sure how to deal with multiple instances and ORM.

Comment: In your code you are just selecting. Don't do that - you need to _reserve_ a record first with an update, then do a select after that and only select the record that you have reserved. Let the database take care of concurrency for you

Comment: How would you do that with an ORM like EF6? And also how to do you handle failed updates?

Comment: A proper programmer would write a class. I would just use `ExecutSqlCommand` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql#sending-raw-commands-to-the-database. What specific case are you referring to with failed updates? For a DB error just handle it, write to a log and continue (or whatever you want to do). If the update doesn't hit a row then that's not a problem

Comment: I made some edits. I'm sure there is a nicer way to `UPDATE` and reserve the row but I've run out of google power for the night

Comment: How is this execution different from what I had in EF6? The main difference I see is that you do the select and the update in 1 transaction instead of 2. Is SQLSERVER processing the transactions sequentially? Because if it's parallel, then i'll have the same exact problem. Just wondering

Comment: Oh sorry yes there is I didn’t realize

Comment: The update is done on SaveChanges() when using EF6.

Comment: The difference in mine is that I go back and read it again afterwards to confirm that the row really was reserved.

Comment: Thank you for the proposition but after testing it, it doesn't seem to resolve the synchronization problem.

Comment: That's a very non specific description of the issue. I've found this pattern to be reliable and I can't see any case where it would allow two processes to try and process the same queue entry.